# Matrix multiplication by vector OpenMP C

Tags: c, openmp

I'm trying to write Matrix by vector multiplication in C (OpenMP)
but my program slows when I add processors...

```
1 proc - 1,3 s
2 proc - 2,6 s
4 proc - 5,47 s
```

I tested this on my PC (core i5) and our school's cluster and the result is the same (program slows)

here is my code (matrix is 10000 x 10000) and vector is 10000:

```
double start_time = clock();
#pragma omp parallel private(i) num_threads(4)
{
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    world_size = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("Threads: %d\n",world_size);

    for(y = 0; y < matrix_size ; y++){
        #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(results, vector, matrix)
        for(i = 0; i < matrix_size; i++){
                results[y] = results[y] + vector[i]*matrix[i][y];   
        }
    }
}
double end_time = clock();
double result_time = (end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Time: %f\n", result_time);
```

My question is: is there any mistake? For me it seems pretty straightforward and should speed up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I essentially already answer this question [parallelizing-matrix-times-a-vector-by-columns-and-by-rows-with-openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277508/parallelizing-matrix-times-a-vector-by-columns-and-by-rows-with-openmp/23277953#23277953).

You have a race condition when you write to `results[y]`.  To fix this, and still parallelize the inner loop, you have to make private versions of `results[y]`, fill them in parallel, and then merge them in a critical section.

In the code below I assume you're using `double`, replace it with `float` or `int` or whatever datatype you're using (note that your inner loop goes over the first index of `matrix[i][y]` which is cache unfriendly).

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
{
    int y,i;
    double* results_private = (double*)calloc(matrix_size, sizeof(double));
    for(y = 0; y < matrix_size ; y++) {
        #pragma omp for
        for(i = 0; i < matrix_size; i++) {
            results_private[y] += vector[i]*matrix[i][y];   
        }
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        for(y=0; y<matrix_size; y++) results[y] += results_private[y];
    }
    free(results_private);
}
```

If this is homework assignment and you want to really impress your instructor then it's possible to do the merging without a critical section.  See this link to get an idea on what to do [fill-histograms-array-reduction-in-parallel-with-openmp-without-using-a-critic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789242/fill-histograms-array-reduction-in-parallel-with-openmp-without-using-a-critic) though I can't promise it will be faster.

Comment: I don't know if I'm correctly interpreting this code.

Comment: @damian, what do you mean?  You mean you're not getting the right answer with it?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed enter :) I don't know if I'm correctly interpreting this code. How it works? results_private is shared among threads or it is private? If it's private: every thread has it's own y variable, and its own results_private and the only thing that is paralleled here is the "i" which will be divided into pieces for example - thead 0 iterating i 0-5000 and thread 1 iterating 5000-10000? But how can you be sure that critical section will be entered by threads in correct order?

Comment: @damian, here is a working example which get's the correct result http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b172dce3c707a55b

Comment: @damian, `results_private` is private (hence the suffix private).  All variables defined in a parallel section are private (so `y` and `i` are private as well).  It does not matter which order the threads enter the critical section (it only matters that when a thread enters it no other thread can enter until that thread finishes).

Comment: Ok thank you very much for help and great answer. One more In relation to this examle how can you be sure that output won't be for example 26, 20, 32? Oh ok, that was stupid question! :)

Comment: @damian, the code is essentially calculating partial sums which don't depend on the thread number (i.e. the order).  So the partial sums are done in parallel and the full sum is done serially.  The point is that the partial sums need O(n^2) calculations and merging only O(n) so the O(n^2) operation dominates (for large enough n).

Comment: Ok I tried this one but still: 1 thread - 3,5s , 2 threads - 3,6s, 4 threads - 6 sec. I tried also increasing matrix size and it didn't help. (still faster on 1 thread)
I'm compiling:
gcc -Wall wektor2.c -o wektor2.o -fopenmp

Comment: @damian, add `-O3` to your compiler options.

Comment: Did not helped, time's still the same.

Comment: @damian, what is your objective?  To parallelize the inner loop or to make your method faster?  If you want to make it faster then parralelize the outer loop as Sergey L. suggested.  My answer is for parallelizing the inner loop (correctly).  For a 10000x10000 matrix merging the partial sums could be slow I guess.  In any case for matricies that size this will be memory bound so if you optimize correctly your code won't be any faster with multiple threads.

Comment: my objective was to make my method faster:)

Comment: @damian, in that case you need to fix your cache usage and not worry about threads.  You want to do `vector[i]*matrix[y][i]`.  Matrix*vector does O(n^2) loads and O(n^2) calculations os it's memory bound and not computation bound.

Comment: It was all about using clock() method for time measuring. While using omp_get_wtime() program speeds up so this is solution to my problem.

Comment: @damian, I'm glad you figured it out.  I should have pointed that out (I alyways use `omp_get_wtime()`).  Your code had other problems as well (a race condition) which I fixed.  It's also still cache unfriendly.

Answer (score 1):

I've not done any parallel programming for a while now, nor any Maths for that matter, but don't you want to split the rows of the matrix in parallel, rather than the columns?

What happens if you try this:

```
double start_time = clock();
#pragma omp parallel private(i) num_threads(4)
{
tid = omp_get_thread_num();
world_size = omp_get_num_threads();
printf("Threads: %d\n",world_size);

#pragma omp parallel for private(y) shared(results, vector, matrix)
for(y = 0; y < matrix_size ; y++){

    for(i = 0; i < matrix_size; i++){
            results[y] = results[y] + vector[i]*matrix[i][y];   
    }
}
}
double end_time = clock();
double result_time = (end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Time: %f\n", result_time);
```

Also, are you sure everything's OK compiling and linking with `openMP`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typical case of cache conflicts.

Consider that a cache line on your CPU is probably 64 bytes long. Having one processor/core write to the first 4 bytes (`float`) causes that cache line to be invalidated on every other L1/L2 and maybe L3. This is a lot of overhead.

Partition your data better!

```
 #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(results, vector, matrix) schedule(static,16)
```

should do the trick. Increase the chunksize if this does not help.

Another optimisation is to store the result locally before you flush it down to memory.

Also, this is an OpenMP thing, but you don't need to start a new parallel region for the loop (each mention of `parallel` starts a new team):

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) \
        shared(vector, matrix) \
        firstprivate(matrix_size) \
        num_threads(4)
{
    int i, y;
    #pragma omp for schedule(static,16)
    for(y = 0; y < matrix_size ; y++){
        double result = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < matrix_size; i++){
                results += vector[i]*matrix[i][y];   
        }
        result[y] = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worse than cache conflicts.  He has a race condition. Each thread is writing to the same range of `y` values.

Comment: Thanks for that, adding schedule(static, 16) speeded things up!

Comment: the scheduler is by default static with a part of your whole data.